# How to extend the Eclipse Java Editor to add coloured overlays

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I have an idea for an Eclipse plugin which I've been toying with. I need to be able to extend the Eclipse Java Editor component and add coloured overlays to the code based on pluggable external metrics. Unfortunately there doesn't appear to be any kind of syntax highlighting extension point.

Does anyone know how I might be able to extend the exisitng eclipse Java Editor to add custom highlighting rules?

Bear in mind I'm new to Eclipse plugin programming so please give as much detail as possible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The base class of the Eclipse 3.5 Java editor is `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java`

Note the "internal" in the class name.  That means it's an internal Eclipse class, and not meant to be extended.

There is an Eclipse extension point `org.eclipse.ui.editors.markerUpdaters`  I've not worked with this extension point, but it appears that it might allow you to do what you wish.

Here's the description from Eclipse help:

> This extension point is used for
>   registering marker update strategies
>   with marker annotation models. A
>   resource that is opened in a text
>   editor is associated with a marker
>   annotation model. For each marker
>   attached to the resource this model
>   manages a position that is updated
>   with each change applied to the text
>   in the editor. If the resource is
>   saved, the text in the editor and the
>   position managed for a marker are
>   passed over to the registered marker
>   update strategies. These strategies
>   can then update the marker's
>   attributes based on the text and the
>   position. Marker update strategies are
>   requested to implement the interface
>   `org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.IMarkerUpdater`.
>   The update strategies can be
>   registered either for a particular
>   marker type or all marker types. The
>   latter by omitting any marker type in
>   the extension.

Here's an example from the Eclipse help:

```
<extension point= "org.eclipse.ui.editors.markerUpdaters"> 
    <updater 
        id="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.markerUpdaters.JavaSearchMarkerUpdater" 
        class="org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.search.JavaSearchMarkerUpdater" 
        markerType="org.eclipse.search.searchmarker"> 
    </updater> 
</extension>
```

I couldn't find more of an explanation on the Internet.